# How can I temporarily disable all autostart services while still allowing me to run apps?

Tags: ram, task-management, services

Because I'm thinking of installing LinuxOnAndroid on my Galaxy Nexus, an old phone with limited RAM (1GB), I need a way to temporarily kill all background services, so they won't use up memory or CPU time.

Everything I could find online only provided ways of disabling specific apps long-term.

Comment: I could use an unusual method like this: Use Greenify (Paid) in root mode without auto-hibernation enabled. Select all the user/system apps in its list that you think wouldn't mess up with system stability and smooth functioning, and whenever you want to kill those selected ones, just push Greenify hibernation. It will do.

Comment: What about rebooting into Safe Boot mode (restart and hold volume down until the lockscreen shows up)?